# Parsing HTML document

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I am trying to parse the following HTML using Ruby and Nokogiri:

```
<div class="vevent">
<table width="750"><tr>
<td width="25"> </td>
<td valign="top" width="200">
<font size="2" face="sans-serif">
<font color="black"><b>June 30, 2015</b></font>
<br>
<span class="dtstart"><span class="value-title" title="2015-06-30"></span></span><br><span class="summary"><font color="#92161" size="3"><b>Band Concert</b></font></span>
<br><font color="#333333">Event</font><br>
<br>
<br>
<br clear="left">Have a question? email us.<br>
<br></font>
</td>
<td valign="top" width="10"></td>
<td valign="top">
<br clear="left"><font color="#92161">111 Main Street</font><br>
<font color="#92161">Mainstreet, Ohio 55111</font>
<a rel="nofollow" href="http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&amp;source=s_q&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;q=%221700+111+MainStreet+NE+Mainstreet,+Ohio+55111%22" target="_blank"><font size="1" face="sans-serif">map link</font></a><br><br>
<font color="#92161"><font size="2" face="sans-serif">Telephone:</font> 3305551000</font><br><br>
Visit our website for complete information.<br><br>
Enjoy a summer evening concert on Main Street at 8pm. Doors and cash bar open at 7pm.<br><br>Look for more details and ticket sales to be released soon on our website<br>  <br><br>
<br>
</td>
</tr></table>
</div>
```

I am trying to grab the last bit of text:

```
Visit our website for complete information.<br><br>
Enjoy a summer evening concert on Main Street at 8pm. Doors and cash bar open at 7pm.<br><br>Look for more details and ticket sales to be released soon on our website<br>  <br><br>
```

Here is my code thus far:

```
events = doc.css("div.vevent")
events.collect do |row|
  row.css("td")[3]  
end
```

This will get me to the third td which has the text that I am looking for as follows:

```
<td valign="top">
<br clear="left"><font color="#92161">111 Main Street</font><br>
<font color="#92161">Mainstreet, Ohio 55111</font>
<a rel="nofollow" href="http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&amp;source=s_q&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;q=%221700+111+MainStreet+NE+Mainstreet,+Ohio+55111%22" target="_blank"><font size="1" face="sans-serif">map link</font></a><br><br>
<font color="#92161"><font size="2" face="sans-serif">Telephone:</font> 3305551000</font><br><br>
Visit our website for complete information.<br><br>
Enjoy a summer evening concert on Main Street at 8pm. Doors and cash bar open at 7pm.<br><br>Look for more details and ticket sales to be released soon on our website<br>  <br><br>
<br>
</td>
```

However once there if I call `text` on that td I get all the text inside of the td.  I only want the last bit that is not inside any element.  I tried using XPath and `parent` so that I could say "just give me the text that is inside the td (not nested inside of another element)" but I couldn't get that to work.  Anyone have any ideas on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code: `doc.css('td')[3].css('> text()').to_s.strip`

Comment: Don't toss out code. Explain *why* the OP would want to use it. Giving a bit of code is equivalent to handing them a fish. Explaining it is equivalent to explaining how to fish. The later is much more useful in the long run.

Comment: This was the right answer.  The part about ('> text()') which indicates just the text inside the td (not the nested elements) is what I needed.  I did update it a bit.  Instead of doc I used row since I am iterating over a bunch of records.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: the Tin Man, I agree, but I understand it looking at the code.  I do think it would be beneficial to have it explained for others who may come across this at a later time though.

Comment: That is exactly the point. Answers are not just for one question or one poster, they're for anyone asking similar questions, which is why we flag duplicate answers, to point people to a single question and its answers. Good answers don't contain only code, they contain explanations which educate.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using `xpath` which is more flexible.
If I understand you correctly, you would like:

> I only want the last bit that is not inside any element

So, try this XPath:

```
//table//td[last()]/text()
```